# Regex для поиска текста с известными символами в начале и в конце

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текстовый файл, в котором собрано много текста, вырезанного из разных книг. Каждый отрезок начинается со строки с заглавием вида "Название книги" и заканчивается строкой "===".
Какое регулярное выражение использовать, чтобы найти весь текст, который начинаются с "Название книги-1" и до строки "==="?
Выражение `Название книги-1.*===` не подходит, т.к. поиск останавливается на символе перевода строки и не доходит до ===.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно библиотека, реализующая регулярные выражениям, включает возможность использовать флаги изменяющее их поведение. Флаг `s` делает так, что символу `.` сопоставляется в том числе и перенос строки (по умолчанию этого не происходит)

Пример на python

```py
re.match(r'Название книги.*===', text, re.S)
```

или

```py
re.match(r'(?s)Название книги.*===', text)
```

Пример на perl

```perl
/Название книги.*===/s;
```

или

```perl
/(?s)Название книги.*===/;
```

Также есть смысл использовать ленивый квантификатор `*?`, если в тексте встречается больше одной книги, иначе `.*` захватит все символы до самого последнего вхождения `===`

```py
>>> re.findall(r'<<<(.*)>>>', '<<<111\n222\n>>><<<333\n444\n>>>', re.S)
['111\n222\n>>><<<333\n444\n']
>>> re.findall(r'<<<(.*?)>>>', '<<<111\n222\n>>><<<333\n444\n>>>', re.S)
['111\n222\n', '333\n444\n']
```